# Linkerd route-based metrics do not work with GKE default ingress controller

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress-controller, linkerd

I have a microservice running in GKE. I am trying to befriend default GKE GCE-ingress with linkerd so that I can observe route-based metrics with linkerd. [The documentation](https://linkerd.io/2.12/tasks/using-ingress/#gce) says that the GCE ingress should be meshed with ingress mode enabled, i.e. with the `linkerd.io/inject: ingress` annotation rather than the default enabled. I tried the following Ingress resource, however route-based metrics are not coming. I checked with `linked tap` command and `rt_route` is not getting set.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  namespace: emojivoto
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-request-headers: "l5d-dst-override: web-svc.emojivoto.svc.cluster.local:80"
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "managed-cert-name"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "static-ip-name"
    linkerd.io/inject: ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: gce
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

I suspect that `linkerd.io/inject: ingress` annotation should be added to ingress controller, however since it is managed by GKE, I do not know how I can add it.

Comment: You're correct that the annotation should be on the ingress controller and not on the ingress resource. I don't know how to get the managed ingress controller annotated on GKE.

Answer (score 0):

The `linkerd.io/inject: ingress` annotation should be added to your deployment(s) or to one or more namespace for automatic injection.

Comment: Indeed, however what to do when ingress controller is not in my deployments as it is managed by GKE?